# Tkinter app collapsing after replacing pack by place

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently working on pretty basic tkinter app, until now I stick to pack methods when it comes package management but then switched over to place since I had less than a dozen widgets which I wanted to place as quickly as possible in desired slots based on x,y coordinates, but now when I run the code this what I get in output, a totally collapsed tkinter app, each time I start it have to stretch it out from the corners or sides, how to fix this ?

[image]

Comment: Try using `<tk.Tk>.geometry` I recommend also looking at the docs

Comment: Thanks, this geometry thing fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

The problem you have run into is caused by the core differences between `place` and `pack`.

When **packing** a widget inside a container widget, the packed widget will be placed as close to the top left corner as possible, leaving room for previously packed widgets. The parent widget (the container) will stretch to the width of the widest child widget and to the height of the sum of all of his children widgets.

When **placing** a widget, the widget will simply be placed with no regards of its parent or siblings. This means that the parent won't stretch, and the siblings won't move out of the way. So when you place widgets, you have to be careful for widgets that are placed out of bounds of their parent or overlapping widgets.

Here is some code to illustrate this.

### Examples

#### Using place

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Text

root = Tk()

large_text = Text(root, height=10)
b1 = Button(root, text="button 1")

large_text.place(x=0, y=0)
b1.place(x=100, y=200)


root.mainloop()
```

[image]

#### Using pack

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Text

root = Tk()

large_text = Text(root, height=10)
b1 = Button(root, text="button 1")

large_text.pack()
b1.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

[image]

#### Solution if you need to use place

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Text

root = Tk()

root.geometry('600x250')
large_text = Text(root, height=10)
b1 = Button(root, text="button 1")

large_text.place(x=0, y=0)
b1.place(x=100, y=200)


root.mainloop()
```

As you can see, you can fix the problem by using `root.geometry` to make the container larger than the position of your placed widgets, but this might not be the best solution in most cases. In my opinion, you should use `grid` or `pack` before `place`, in most cases, they will be better suited.

[image]

Comment: Yup, used the same geometry method to fix the issue and it worked, thanks.

Comment: Your opening statement about a widget being packed as close as possible to the top left corner is false. By default it will be centered along the top edge. The description of the containing widget is also somewhat inaccurate.